# Dig holes in Android layouts

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to create holes in an Android layout.I have two backgrounds, one normal, one blurred, and what I want to create cells that can display the blurred background.

My XML would be constructed like this:

Background_blurred > Background_normal > Cells.

-I already know how to blur a background.

-Cells are everywhere, like a GridView, and not just on the borders.[image]

Comment: Can you make a picture? just to figure out what you mean.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, but I'd like to see if anyone comes up with something. Upvote. Well, it might be possible with a custom view where you handle the drawing of all the cells, but I don't see an easy way to do it in the layout or with a GridView.

Comment: Right now I can only imagine 2 layered bitmaps: 1 (blurred) as the background. And another one (non blurred) with holes, like an Emmenthal cheese slice, over the background.

Comment: The only way to "kind of" make a hole in the layout structure is to use a SurfaceView, but I'm not sure you would be able to use it in an AdaterView, nor it will be possible to show the background. But it's the place for you to start your research: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html

Comment: sure: do a custom backgroud deawing in dispatchDraw() of your layout

Comment: If it's your own ViewGroup implementation and the Cells are also custom Views, you could maybe pass a background offset to the Cells that show the blurred image as a background, so they appear like a hole to the blurred image. The non-hole cells would just have invisible backgrounds so the ViewGroup's background would show through.

Comment: I updated my question with a image, and Tenfour04 : This view is scrollable, so the image is moving with the blur effect

Comment: What will happen when you'll have many items in the list so it will be longer than the image? is it possible?

Comment: The image is still, but the effect moves with the cells, or at least have to.

Comment: @Tsunaze my answer is still valid: use dispatchDraw()

Comment: do you have some kind of example with dispatchDraw() ? Or you use it like onDraw ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
class FL extends FrameLayout {
    private List<View> mViews = new ArrayList<View>();
    private Bitmap mBack;
    private Bitmap mBackBlur;
    private int[] mLocation = new int[2];
    private Matrix mMatrix = new Matrix();

    public FL(Context context) {
        super(context);
        Resources res = getResources();
        mBack = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.back);
        mBackBlur = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.back_blur);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        RectF src = new RectF(0, 0, mBack.getWidth(), mBack.getHeight());
        RectF dst = new RectF(0, 0, w, h);
        mMatrix.setRectToRect(src, dst, ScaleToFit.FILL);
    }

    public void add(View v) {
        mViews.add(v);
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBack, mMatrix, null);

        canvas.save(Canvas.CLIP_SAVE_FLAG);
        getLocationOnScreen(mLocation);
        int x = mLocation[0];
        int y = mLocation[1];
        Op op = Op.REPLACE;
        for (View v : mViews) {
            v.getLocationOnScreen(mLocation);
            mLocation[0] -= x;
            mLocation[1] -= y;

            int left = mLocation[0];
            int top = mLocation[1];
            int right = left + v.getWidth();
            int bottom = top + v.getHeight();
            canvas.clipRect(left, top, right, bottom, op);
            op = Op.UNION;
        }
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBackBlur, mMatrix, null);
        canvas.restore();
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

testing code (in onCreate):

```
    FL fl = new FL(this);
    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    float[] hsv = {
            0, 1, 0.75f
    };
    float[] h = {
            0, 39, 60, 120, 300
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        hsv[0] = h[i];
        tv.setTextColor(0xffeeeeee);
        tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.HSVToColor(128, hsv));
        tv.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        tv.setTextSize(64);
        tv.setText("#" + i);
        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.topMargin = 10;
        params.bottomMargin = 10;
        params.leftMargin = 20;
        params.rightMargin = 20;
        ll.addView(tv, params);
        fl.add(tv);
    }
    sv.addView(ll);
    fl.addView(sv);
    setContentView(fl);
```

where R.drawable.back is:

[image]

and R.drawable.back_blur is:

[image]

the result is:

[image]

Comment: Wow, it's really good, but it has some problems (distortions) : The image in blur is smaller and it shrink when i scroll. I'll get into this solution.

Comment: Ha, the blurred background is still shifted (and smaller), maybe the size of my images are not the same and that's why the effect is distored when i scroll to far. I'll get back to you. But this is a great improvement!

Comment: see if both pngs are the same size and in the same folder

Comment: I've edited to erase the distortion effect, i just need to check the value of the top to be always positive or equal to zero

Comment: i've edited as well: this is how it should look like (more or less)