# Efficiently replace parts of Bitmap during animation?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-animation

I've got custom sliding view, which I can move up and down, over another view (ImageView).

I've also got blurred version of said view prepared in memory. What I want to achive is blurring this background view during sliding up/down as I would cover it with a blurry glass. Also, I need to reverse this process too, that's why I'm keeping both Bitmaps.

Hope I made myself clear here.

sadly, this project requires me to use API >= 8

Comment: something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21580299/dig-holes-in-android-layouts ?

Comment: That's a nice idea, gonna give it a try. Thank you.